# Make Monogame window click-through

Tags: c#, windows, overlay, monogame

I'm new to MonoGame and I'm trying to make an overlay (top-most, transparent and click-through).
I managed to do the first two things but can't get the third one.

This is what I tried:

```
internal class User32 {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
}
```

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    public IntPtr FormHandle { get; private set; }
    public Form Form { get; private set; }

    private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
    private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

    public Game1()
    {
        _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }
        
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        FormHandle = this.Window.Handle;
        Form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(FormHandle).FindForm();

        //make it topmost and click-through
        Form.TopMost = true;
        int initialStyle = User32.GetWindowLong(Form.Handle, -20);
        User32.SetWindowLong(Form.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);

        //make it transparent and borderless
        Form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        //Form.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        Form.Opacity = 0.5;
        Form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            
        base.Initialize();
    }

    [...]
}
```

This is the only way I found. It works on a windows form application I have but doesn't on monogame. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
I just realised the window is click-through, but only the drawn area is not. I only have png background and the transparent area of it is click-through, but the colored area is not

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating your code to the constructor and a one-shot in Update. The window is initialized after construction and most properties are set internally after construction. Some are set later.

Comment: I just realised the window is click-through, but only the drawn area is not. I only have png background and the transparent area of it is click-through, but the colored area is not.